# Basics of using the Microsoft Async Framework

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-ctp

Using Visual Studio Async CTP (Version 3) I am struggling to understand how I can "wrap" existing code using this framework.

For example

Using the OpenPop.NET library I am trying to establish a connection with a pop3 server and confirm I have a valid username and password.

So lets say I have some code like this.

```
    public bool ConnectSync()
    {
        bool success = true;
        Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client();

        try
        {
            client.Connect("mail.server.com", 110, false);
            client.Authenticate("username", "password");
        }
        catch
        {
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }
```

And now I want to make it Async my understanding from what I have been reading and piecing together is that I would end up with a method signature along the lines of

```
    public async Task<bool> ConnectAsync()
    {

    }
```

I believe this is the correct signature because it will be a task that returns a boolean(?) and my guess is that I will need to utilize the TaskEx.Run() method? but that's as far as I can seem to get my head around. Could anyone point in the right direction?

Comment: Things that introduced with Async CTP are not a framework AFAIK, are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right so far.

The easy way to convert your method is, as you say, just to wrap it in `TaskEx.Run` so the method runs on a thread pool thread and doesn't block your UI thread.

```
public Task<bool> ConnectAsync()
{
    return TaskEx.Run( () =>
        {
            bool success = true;
            Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client();

            try
            {
                client.Connect("mail.server.com", 110, false);
                client.Authenticate("username", "password");
            }
            catch
            {
                success = false;
            }
            return success;
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, in order to reap the most benefits from the async CTP you could really do with async calls all the way down. You can wrap your *synchronous* `ConnectSync` method in a task very easily, without using the async CTP at all:

```
// Note: not an async method in itself
public Task<bool> ConnectAsync()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(ConnectSync);
}
```

(It's possible that you don't have to specify the type argument here - I can never remember the exact rules for type inference using method group conversions.)

That will still tie up a thread while it's connecting though. If you're okay with that, then at least you'll end up with a method you can *call* from an async method and await appropriately. If nothing else, this will allow you to build the rest of your application upwards using async, and then if/when the POP3 code supports async, you can just rewrite `ConnectAsync` to be an async method.